# Constrain UIScrollView panning?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

UIScrollView has a built-in behavior "directionLockEnabled".

When enabled, panning will attempt to lock to either the horizontal or vertical directions.  But when the user aggressively attempts to scroll diagonally - it still allows diagonal scrolling.

I'd like to remove the ability to diagonally scroll.

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I've tried putting a UIScrollView inside another (each with dimensions so as to constrain the movement) but the pan recognizers seemed to conflict - only one worked.

I've looked at TTScrollView to see if it could be modified for the job - but it does not seem to be working properly out of the box (freezing after first gesture.)

I've tried adding a second action (listener) to UIScrollView.panGestureRecognizer to call setTranslation:inView with a constrained value.  This resulted in erratic jumping.

And several other avenues probably not worth mentioning.

EDIT2:

Odrakir's solution works.  Code looks like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Sofia"];
    UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024 * 2, 768 * 2);

    UIScrollView* scrollView1 = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024*2, 768)];
    scrollView1.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1024*2, 768*2);
    [scrollView1 addSubview:imageView];

    UIScrollView* scrollView2 = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
    scrollView2.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1024*2, 768);
    [scrollView2 addSubview:scrollView1];

    [self.view addSubview:scrollView2];
}
```

Comment: put some code to explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never tried that, but I have an app that has a horizontal ScrollView, and inside it there are multiple views, each of them with their own vertical ScrollView.

It's kind of like a magazine, with different articles and each article has a number of pages.

Both ScrollViews work and the user can't scroll diagonally. You can try that.

The display hierarchy is Horizontal ScrollView-> View ->Vertical ScrollView

Comment: This seems to be working - I'll post some working code once I get the kinks out.  Many thanks.